# Display static values in SQL

Tags: sql, plsql, oracle-apex

I have a query where I  display date and order count in oracle apex

```
select date,order_count where status = 'follow up'
```

I have result like this-

[image]

We get order count for each day and daily the order count changes for all the previous days(i.e- < sysdates).

My requirement is -my count should be static for **all** previous days.

For example,the order count for 2 sep-2015 is 469,tomorrow the count might change to 490.
But In my case,tomorrow also my count should be 469  even if the orginal count for 2- sep-2015  changes to 490 tomorrow.

Comment: Make a static table with `id` and `count` and `date` column and make the `id` of your current table to refer the static table as foreign_key,and specify

    `ON UPDATE NO ACTION` it'll work.

Comment: How about: SELECT Date, COUNT(*) FROM TableA WHERE Status = 'follow up' GROUP BY Date;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi I used insert statement in stored procedure which stores only yesterday's data(sysdate -1) and scheduled a daily job.This keeps my value static in my table